# django issue with image encoding on upload

Tags: python, django, django-models, utf-8, django-views

I have some issues with saving images with swedish characters such as `ö å ö`

I am getting a traceback of the following

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/project/project/41/
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    ö
Exception Location: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib.py in quote, line 1216

......

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/urllib.py in quote
res = map(safe_map.__getitem__, s)
```

Can anyone give some advice why this is happening, and how I can resolve this issue?

your feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I used pythons Unidecode to decode the file before upload.

One thing I've learned, always decode before encoding.